# Retrieve data faster through sqlalchemy query to RDS (Aurora) Database

Tags: mysql, performance, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have tried querying data with (50000 records and 40 columns) from database, it is taking me around 200 seconds even after I have applied indexing, is there any way to reduce size of the response of the query from database to get data more quicckly?? I'm using RDS (Aurora MySQL)

```
class Vehicles(Base):
    'Class for creating Job Car Result Table'
    __tablename__ = 'jobs_car_result_tbl'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    
    job_id = Column('job_id', Integer, ForeignKey('jobs_tbl.job_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    jobID = synonym('job_id')
    
    sub_job_id = Column('sub_job_id', Integer)
    subJobID = synonym('sub_job_id')
    
    device_id = Column('device_id', String(64))
    deviceID = synonym('device_id')
    
    datetime = Column('datetime', DateTime)
    dateTime = synonym('datetime')
    
    line_name = Column('line_name', String(128, collation='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'))
    lineName = synonym('line_name')
    
    direction = Column('direction', String(64, collation='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'))
    
    tracking_id = Column('tracking_id', Integer)
    trackingID = synonym('tracking_id')
    
    x = Column('x', Integer)
    
    y = Column('y', Integer)
    
    w = Column('w', Integer)
    
    h = Column('h', Integer)
    
    vehicle_color = Column('vehicle_color', String(64))
    vehicleColor = synonym('vehicle_color')
    
    vehicle_class = Column('vehicle_class', String(64))
    vehicleClass = synonym('vehicle_class')
    
    st_trunk_trailer = Column('st_trunk_trailer', String(64))
    stTrunkTrailer = synonym('st_trunk_trailer')
    
    st_vehicle_backup = Column('st_vehicle_backup', String(64))
    stVehicleBackup = synonym('st_vehicle_backup')
    
    st_automobile_angle = Column('st_automobile_angle', String(64))
    stAutomobileAngle = synonym('st_automobile_angle')
    
    st_vehicle_sunroof = Column('st_vehicle_sunroof', String(64))
    stVehicleSunroof = synonym('st_vehicle_sunroof')
    
    st_vehicle_luggage_rack = Column('st_vehicle_luggage_rack', String(64))
    stVehicleLuggageRack = synonym('st_vehicle_luggage_rack')
    
    st_vehicle_characters = Column('st_vehicle_characters', String(64))
    stVehicleCharacters = synonym('st_vehicle_characters')
    
    st_vehicle_sticker = Column('st_vehicle_sticker', String(64))
    stVehicleSticker = synonym('st_vehicle_sticker')
    
    st_danger_strip = Column('st_danger_strip', String(64))
    stDangerStrip = synonym('st_danger_strip')
    
    st_truck_style = Column('st_truck_style', String(64))
    stTruckStyle = synonym('st_truck_style')
    
    size = Column('size', String(64))
```

I'm expecting that records should appear in 30 sec, as I'm using AWS Appsync for API implementation and 30 sec is a hard time limit for Appsync request.

```
Vehicle_result = reader_session.query(Vehicles).filter(Vehicles.jobID == 7).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably somewhere between

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/performance.html#result-fetching-slowness-core

and

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/performance.html#result-fetching-slowness-orm

I don't use SQLAlchemy myself, but ORMs in general are vulnerable to fetching too many columns and/or too many rows and then doing the filtering in memory. If you don't need all the columns in your result set, only retrieve the columns that you use. If the query is bringing back all 50,000 rows and then looping through them in memory to find the ones with a job ID of 7, there must be a way to rearrange the .filter() and .all() calls (also if it's somehow doing a join behind the scenes) to have the database chop down the result set before it sends you the results. (That rearrangement is the precise detail I don't know for SQLAlchemy.)